# Firebase notification click-on crashed when ios app is closed

Tags: objective-c, firebase, push-notification, firebase-notifications, navigationcontroller

When I click the notification, I want it to open a notification viewController of the app. All codes are in AppDelegate.m

I have a function to find the topMostController

```
- (UIViewController *)topMostController {
    UIViewController *topController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
    while (topController.presentedViewController) {
        topController = topController.presentedViewController;
    }
    return topController;
}
```

Then there's another function to display the notification viewController

```
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)[self topMostController];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryBoard" bundle:nil];

    MyViewController *myController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];

    [navigationController pushViewController:myController animated:YES];
```

It works fine if the app is open. However, when the app is closed, it will crash if I click the notification. The error is

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
-[ViewController pushViewController:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I think there's no topMostController or the navigationController is invalid in such. I need to use the UINavigationController because I want a "back" button to go back to a page (main page) rather than closing the app. How could I make the topMostController valid in such case? Should I create something inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need to assign root view controller

```
   self.navigationController = RootNavigationControllerViewController(rootViewController: HomeViewController.init())



    self.window?.rootViewController =  self.navigationController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: Should I add this inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function? The HomeViewController also contains a navigationController. Probably the best way is to load the welcome page?

Comment: In that case you can simply update your rootview controller with homeview controller Thanks